# Animate 1 object that's part of a group

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Power Point 2007

Would anyone know if it's possible to animate a single object of a group?   I have what's basically a collection of boxes with a couple of images that's group togather so that the whole group animates in and out.   Between those animations I need a single object in the group to animate out (before the whole group).

Every time I try to create an animation for the single object, power point creates the animation for the whole group.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about popping a duplicate of the shape you want to animate over the group (same position as the original shape), making the original shape invisible, then animating your duplicate?